# Finding empty cell then loop to get new data

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm have a spreadsheet that takes 31 different tabs with daily data, then summarizes it into a monthly tab, then converts each day's data into a software upload. In order to expedite my process I'm trying to combine every daily upload into another tab at once instead of copy/pasting each day manually. Currently to see the upload for each day I am changing the number in cell B3 to the day I need and it will give me the upload data.

EDIT:

How I hope this will work is the macro will put "1" in cell B3 on the Upload tab, take the data in A10:I34, paste it over to the first empty cell in column A on the Upload Files tab, then go back to the upload tab, change cell B3 to "2", copy the data in A10:I34, paste it to the next empty cell in column A on the Upload Files tab... repeat until the data from day 31 has been pasted onto the Upload Files tab.

1. Data is in tab called "Upload"
2. The only cell that can change on tab "Upload" is cell "B3"
3. Data range is "A10:I34"
4. Data needs to paste values on tab "Upload Files"
5. "Upload Files" has formatting data in row 1 needed for the software

EDIT:

6. The macro needs to looks for the next empty row after each day's data has been pasted
7. Loop needs to stop at day 31

My issue now is that I can't get it to go back to the upload tab and change the date to the next day and then continue with the empty cell loop. It ends up just pasting the data over the original data, or not changing the cell value to the next day. Below is what I have for changing the days.

EDIT #3: I tweaked it, it works now. Please take a look and let me know if you think it could be improved. Added For/next.

---

```
Dim Count as integer

Dim x as Long

Count = 2

For x = 1 to 30

   Do While Worksheets("Upload Files").Range("A" & Count).Value <> ""

      Count = Count +1

   Loop

      Worksheets ("Upload").Range("B3").Value = Worksheets("Upload").Range("B3").Value +1
      Worksheets("Upload").Range("A10:I34").Copy
      Worksheets("Upload Files").Range("A" & Count).PasteSpecial xl PasteValues
Next x
```

---

Any suggestions? Previous attempts just simply selected the exact cell where the previous data ended on the "Upload Files" tab, but adding rows in the "Upload" tab means I have to manually recalculate which cells the data will be pasted, which is about as time consuming as doing the whole thing manually.

Thanks,

Comment: Problem might be that you are resetting Count to 2 each time you run the macro? Also the range you copy does not have a sheet specified.

Comment: the count reset is intentional, the data cannot be pasted in row 1, so when it looks for the next empty cell it has to start in "A2". The sheet mistake I didn't even notice! Thank you!

Comment: And the other point?

Comment: I think it would need to start at 2 every time, because I copy the previous upload files tab to a new tab ( for reference purposes after the upload is done) and then delete all of the data from the Upload Files tab, so I think it would make more sense for it to start from the top again rather than the last count value

Answer (score 1):

I added some comments for your understanding inside the code:

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Count = 2

    ' This would give you the last used row in the Sheet
    lLastRow = Worksheets("Upload Files").Cells(Worksheets("Upload Files").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lLastRow

        ' You don't specify if you are trying to do anything in this section inside de Loop
        ' but if you just want to cound for the last row, you can remove the loop.
    Next i


    If Worksheets("Upload").Range("B3").Value < 32 Then

        ' Dont need this.
        'Worksheets("Upload").Range("B3").Select

        Worksheets("Upload").Range("B3").Value = Worksheets("Upload").Range("B3").Value + 1

        ' Here it would be nice if you specify from what Sheet you are copying this range. I guess is Upload.
        Worksheets("Upload").Range("A10:I34").Copy
        Worksheets("Upload Files").Range("A" & Count).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I just suggest to use `Long` instead of `Integer`. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle and there is no benefit in using `Integer` at all in VBA.

Comment: Integer was the variable he was using. I used long for the two variables added. But yeah @malbane, don't need to use integer as Pᴇʜ mentioned.

Comment: The maximum amount of rows that would be copied is 1085, is that too much for integer?

Comment: The code is (hopefully) going to loop back after pasting into the second tab and get the next day. So theoretically it would get day 1's data from the Upload tab, paste it into the first empty row on the "upload files" tab, then go back to the Upload tab and get day 2's data, which would then be pasted under the first day's data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're after something like follows:

```
Option Explicit
Sub upload()
    Dim targetSht As Worksheet
    Set targetSht = Worksheets("Upload Files")
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("Upload")
        For i = 1 To 31
            .Range("B3").Value = i
            Application.Calculate

            With .Range("A10:I34")
                targetSht.Cells(targetSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```